# Inserting text in a file from a variable

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

I have a shell variable that looks something like this:

```
var="MRD"
```

What I want to do, is to make my file look like this:

```
ABC
MRD
DEF
GHI
```

I was trying to do this:

```
sed -i -e 's/ABC/&$var/g' text.txt
```

but it only inserts $var instead of the value. I also tried this:

```
sed -i -e 's/ABC/&"$var"/g' text.txt
```

but that didn't work either. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works.

```
var="MRD"
sed 's/ABC/&\n'"${var}"'/' text.txt
```

**EDIT**

We can use any character instead of /. So if we expect it to be in the search or replace expression, use |

```
var="</stuff>"
sed 's|ABC|&\n'"${var}"'|' text.txt
```

Comment: That works with var="MRD". Now how would you do it if the var="</stuff>". Edit: I probably need to escape everything ugh.

Comment: ...that still means you can't work with arbitrary text -- if your string has a `|` in it that needs to be escaped. Using awk or perl can get you away from this gotcha by referring to environment variables or argv entries; sed doesn't have an equivalent mechanism.

Comment: Agreed @Charles. If I were to do it from scratch, I would also prefer awk to sed which gives much better control. I am only extending the OP's question as it may be part of a bigger script or something that can't easily be changed to awk. Assuming the input and replacement is well understood, in almost all situation one character can be found that can be used as separator in sed.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick since I don't have | in my string. Thanks Charles, Amit!

Comment: One last suggestion -- make it `'"${var}"'` rather than just `'${var}'` -- the latter approach means that whitespace or shell wildcards inside the variable could result in string-splitting or wildcard expansion.

Answer (score 2):

sed can do [more than search and replace](http://man.cx/sed) -- it can append:

```
sed "/ABC/a $var"
```

In some older versions of sed, you have to write

```
sed "/ABC/a\\
$var"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var='<stuff>' awk '{ print $0 } NR==1 { print ENVIRON["var"]; }' \
  <<<$'ABC\nDEF\nGHI' \
```

yields

```
ABC
<stuff>
DEF
GHI
```

To do an in-place replacement:

```
tempfile=$(mktemp "${infile}.XXXXXX")
awk ... <"$infile" >"$tempfile" \
  && mv "$tempfile" "$infile"
```

Note that `var` needs to be in the environment -- so if you aren't defining it on the same line where you invoke awk, you should `export` it.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes disable variable interpolation; double quotes do not.

```
sed -i -e "s/ABC/&$var/g" text.txt
```

(Note that this isn't such a good idea when `$var` contains `/` or any other character that `sed` treats specially.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to terminate the single quotes (which prevent interpolation) before you can switch to the double quotes, or just use double quotes to start with.

That said, the `s` command changes the current line, it does not insert lines; you would end up with a single line containing `DEFMRD`, not `MRD` inserted on its own line.  For that, you want something like

```
sed -i -e "/ABC/a\\
$var\\
." text.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`:

```
awk "{print \$0}NR==1{print \"$var\"}" text.txt
```

or if `var` has been exported:

```
export var=MRD
awk '{print $0}NR==1{print ENVIRON["var"]}' text.txt
```

Comment: If you're using awk, you can (and should!) pass variables through the environment rather than needing to escape them to safely pass through the shell.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf '2i\n%s\n.\nw\n' "$var" | ed -s text.txt
```